# python datetime now without daylight savings

Tags: python, datetime

I'm lost in the tzinfo documentation.

I want to create a datetime object for my location which does not include an adjustment for daylight savings.

At the moment I am ugly hacking it:

```
import time
import datetime
now=datetime.datetime.now()
if time.localtime().tm_isdst==1:
    now=now+datetime.timedelta(hours=-1)
```

What's the right way?

Comment: Your solution seems reasonable to me and quite clear as well.

Comment: I disagree - at the moment I have a datetime object which is classed as daylight savings inclusive, but is an hour ago rather than actually now. This could create confusion if I start to do comparisons with other datetime objects. I'm looking for a way to instantiate a datetime object which has no daylight savings in its tzinfo, and hence no need for magic numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to create a "bogus" time by removing the effect of DST, your current solution will work.

However, the best practice for working with dates is representing all dates as UTC internally, and only deal with timezone differences for user interaction.  This way you don't have to care about all the messy details.

To add support for all timezones to your program, consider using [PyTZ](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: +1 for the recommendation to use UTC - that really is the right way. UTC is unambiguous, which is an essential property when working with time.

Comment: I don't want a bogus time, else I wouldn't have asked - thanks for the PyTZ recommendation

Comment: @meepmeep: Maybe you don't want bogus times any more, now that people have recommended you to use UTC times instead... ;)